# Xamarin.Android dependency netstandard13 package?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard-1.5

According to the [docs on the .NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md), it seems like it should be possible for Xamarin apps to consume NuGet packages targetin netstandard13. However, when I try this I get the following error while trying to add the NuGet:

```
 Unable to find a version of 'System.Collections.Concurrent' that is compatible with 'npgsql 3.9.0 constraint: System.Collections.Concurrent (>= 4.0.12-rc2-24027)'.
```

I'm trying to do this on VS2015 update 2 + RC2 tooling. Is this not possible, is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That npgsql package seems to be depending on pre-release packages (RC - Release Candidate). Run the install with -pre option:

```
Install-Package npgsql -pre
```